# SDL2, create window bigger than screen

Tags: c++, image, sdl, sdl-2

i am trying to create a window in SDL2 by using:

```
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("nada",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,image->w, image->h, 0);
```

where image->h and image->w are the height and width of the image i am trying lo render(2000 and 600).

I want to create a window the size of an image i have. The image is 2000x600 pixels, but my screen is 1920x1080 and when the window is created it shrinks to the size of the screen.

How can i create a window the size of the image? i mean, bigger than the screen?

Comment: How are you calling SDL_CreateWindow();, what flags? show the code.

Answer (score 1):

After [`SDL_CreateWindow()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) call [`SDL_SetWindowSize()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowSize). This seems to work for me.

It seems as though `SDL_CreateWindow()` is limited by the screen size and `SDL_SetWindowSize()` is not.

`SDL_CreateWindow()` will lock in maximized mode if you send parameters with a resolution too high, causing `SDL_SetWindowSize()` not to work. So try sending a low resolution to `SDL_CreateWindow()` ( like 10x10 ) and the resolution you want for `SDL_SetWindowSize()`.

**EDIT**

`SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` must **NOT** be passed to `SDL_CreateWindow()`. This causes the window to be locked in maximized mode, therefore limiting the window to the screens's resolution. If you do this you shouldn't need `SDL_SetWindowSize`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The SDL is limited by your OS and driver. You probably are at the largest resolution possible and your video card probably can not handle anything more than that. You still could try to load that on memory and then zoom and or pan the image. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: But i could do it on sdl1.2.
The thing is that i want to take a screenshot. i used to do it with SDL_SaveBMP() from the screen, but that isnt avaliable any more. Now i can use SDL_RenderReadPixels(), save them on a surface and then save the bmp of the surface, but it i try to save it on a new surface that is bigger than the screen, a black square appears, buecause the renderer just renders the resolution size.